# Is there an easy way to bind all available types to a concrete instance

Tags: c#, ninject

I have the following interfaces and concrete implementations:

```
interface IFoo {
      string Name { get ;}
}

class Foo :IFoo{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

interface IBar {
     string Name { get; }
}

class Bar : IBar {
     public string Name { get;set;}

     public Bar(Foo foo) {

     }
}
```

You can see that Bar has a dependency on Foo in the class constructor.

These are my bindings:

```
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToConstant(new Foo() { Name="Foo"; });
kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();
```

When I use `kernel.Get` and ask for Bar, there are no errors, but the Foo dependency is a different instance of `Foo` that I originally bound. I expected to see Foo with a name of "Foo" when I inspect the Foo instance inside of the Bar constructor, but instead I see Foo { Name = null }.

When I bind to concrete Foo, everything works as expected:

```
var foo = new Foo() { Name="Foo" };
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToConstant(foo);
kernel.Bind<Foo>().ToConstant(foo);
kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>();

var bar= kernel.Get<Bar>(); // works! foo has name "Foo"
```

Is there a convenient way to bind a specific instance of Foo to all the available interfaces, and concrete types?

For example:

```
class ConcreteFoo : AbstractFoo, IFoo {
   ...
}

var foo = new Foo();
kernel.Bind<IFoo>().ToConstant(foo);
kernel.Bind<AbstractFoo>().ToConstant(foo);
kernel.Bind<ConcreteFoo>().ToConstant(foo);
```

I have a generic framework. Outside of the framework is Foo and Bar that the clients define. I want clients to have the flexibility of specifying IFoo or Foo in the Bar constructor. If the constructor was defined as Bar(IFoo), the client might be casting it to Foo anyway.

Comment: this seems a little strange to me, as in what is the real use case. In my mind, `Bar` should be asking for an `IFoo`. The whole point of dependency inversion.

Comment: It sounds to me like named dependencies is more what you need. I would let the client cast the `Foo`, because this follows the inversion principle.

Comment: Would named dependencies allow me to conveniently have one binding, and it would work for all derived types and interfaces.  Could you give me a quick example?

Comment: na they won't. You need to bind each type. There's some syntactic sugar so you can make a multi-type binding, like `Bind<IFoo, Foo>().ToConstant(new Foo())`. This binds the instance to both `IFoo` and `Foo`.

Comment: can you explain who's doing the binding and what the task of the framework is? How do you ensure there's not multiple implementation of `IFoo`? Multiple children of `AbstractFoo`? how do you know which to instanciate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such functionality provided by ninject. What ninject offers is binding to multiple types, for example:

```
Bind<IFoo,Foo>().To<Foo>().InSingletonScope();
```

Ensures no matter what combination of `IFoo` and `Foo` are requested, you always get the same `Foo` instance.

Then, there's [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) which can look for types (like all classes of an assembly) and bind them to all their interface, all their base types,... but only either or, not both. You could use this to achieve what you want, but it would require quite some code on your end, too,.. and it would be kind of akward.

So, in my opinion, it's best just to roll your own:

```
using Ninject.Infrastructure.Language;

public static void RegisterConstantAsAllTypes(IBindingRoot bindingRoot, object instance)
{
    Type t = instance.GetType();

    IEnumerable<Type> typesToBind = t.GetAllBaseTypes()
        .Concat(t.GetInterfaces())
        .Except(new[] { typeof(object) });

    bindingRoot
        .Bind(typesToBind.ToArray())
        .ToConstant(instance);
}
```

Given your example the following test passes:

```
[Fact]
public void FactMethodName()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    var foo = new Foo();
    RegisterConstantAsAllTypes(kernel, foo);

    kernel.Get<IFoo>().Should().Be(foo);
    kernel.Get<Foo>().Should().Be(foo);
    kernel.Get<AbstractFoo>().Should().Be(foo);
}
```